# Series, and Root Test and Limit:

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I was given the following series to find out if it absolutely converges or conditionally converges, or if diverges.

> $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{2^{n^2}}{n!}$$

I decided to venture on this one with the Root Test to find out if it converges, or diverges. I got this point:

> $$\displaystyle \lim_\limits{n \to \infty} (\vert \dfrac{2^{n^2}}{n!} \vert)^{\frac{1}n}$$
>   Which lead me to the following:
>   $$\lim_\limits{n \to \infty} \dfrac{2^n}{(n!)^\frac{1}n}$$

I went to wolfram alpha and it says the limit is $\infty$, meaning the series diverges which it does. How do I solve this limit?

Comment: I'll propose an inequality that will help you: $n! \le n^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just as a side note, this problem would probably be solved much easier with the ratio test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). But it is more natural to prove that the series diverges using the ratio test:$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{2^{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{2n+1}}{n+1}=\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

For working with factorials,
use
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n!)^{1/n}}{n/e}
=1
$.